# MySQL Update only ONE empty field

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE column=''");
```

I want to update the first empty field in a column in my database. The problem I'm having is I have multiple empty values in my DB and the above code updates all empty values in the mentioned column. I'd like to change the code to update only one of the empty values. Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET column='value' WHERE column='' order by some_field LIMIT 1");
```